# Realizar UNPIVOT no Excel para importar no Access

Tags: microsoft-excel

Possuo uma tabela com o seguinte formato:

[image: Formato atual da tabela]

Como a primeira coluna e a primeira linha são campos de código, preciso que fique no seguinte formato, para importação no MS Access:

[image: Formato Final da Tabela]

É possível fazer manualmente, mas como a tabela é MUITO extensa, gostaria de saber se tem algum modo de fazer isso automaticamente? Isso iria me poupar uns bons 3 dias de trabalho.

O Excel é a versão 2010 pt-BR. O Access é o 2003, também em português. Sobre as linhas com o código igual, apenas ignorem, pois foi um exemplo que criei e acabei não alterando, todos os códigos são únicos na tabela real.

Comment: Qual sua versão de Excel? 2007, 2010... Ta em portugues, ingles, ..?

Comment: Você percebeu que você possui linhas duplicadas na sua coluna A, por exemplo: `685251`, o que fazer nesses casos?

Comment: Olá, sobre as linhas duplicadas, eu criei como um exemplo apenas, mas as chaves serão todas distintas. Foi algo que deixei passar. O Excel 2010 em português.

Comment: Isto? http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/unpivot-columns-HA104053356.aspx

Comment: Não entendi por que negativaram a pergunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Praticamente voce tá querendo dar um **UNPIVOT**

Aplique a solução dessa outra questão e deve resolver o seu problema:

[is-it-possible-to-unpivot-or-reverse-pivot-in-excel](https://superuser.com/questions/78439/is-it-possible-to-unpivot-or-reverse-pivot-in-excel)

Comment: É isso mesmo. Muito orbgiado!